# Бесконечно крутится ProgressBar в OnRefresh, имплементированный от SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

При свайпе вниз в RecyclerView вызывается метод OnRefresh, появляется ProgressBar. При окончании работы метода OnRefresh, ProgressBar продолжает бесконечно крутиться. Он не исчезает. Как заставить его исчезнуть?

MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    parser.showListNewChapter(new Handler(msg -> {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case HandlerWhat.ERROR_CONNECTION_DOCUMENT:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Не удалось подключиться к серверу. Повторите попытку позже", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
        }

        Bundle bundleData = msg.getData();
        mAdapter.listNewChapter =bundleData.getParcelableArrayList(Parser.LIST_NEW_CHAPTER);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }));
}
```

Parser

```
public void showListNewChapter(Handler callbackUI) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Document documentNewestCh;
            documentNewestCh = Jsoup.connect(URL_NEWEST_CHAPTERS).timeout(20000).get();
            listNewChapterFromNewestCh = documentNewestCh.select("ul.area_rightNews.linkStyle li");

            ArrayList<Chapter> listNewChapter = runSearchNewChapter(new OffsetAndLimit(0, 16));

            Bundle bundleData = getBundle(listNewChapter);
            Message messageHandler = getMessage(bundleData);
            callbackUI.sendMessage(messageHandler);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            callbackUI.sendEmptyMessage(HandlerWhat.ERROR_CONNECTION_DOCUMENT);
        }
    }, "Thread Connect Site").start();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При окончании загрузки надо вызывать `mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);`